# Take that factorialize function and step through it

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Please explain. Line return num * factorialize(num - 1). Assume we have an integer 5 as an argument. Must be 5 * factorialize(5-1) = 5 * 4 = 20. How we getting to 120?

```
function factorialize(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
        return 1;
}

    return num * factorialize(num - 1);
}

factorialize(5)
```

Comment: Walk through the call to `factorialize(4)`... it will not return immediately as `num` is not zero. So what does it do?

Comment: `factorialize(x)` will always return factorial of *x*. So, `5 * factorialize(5-1) = 5 * 4! = 5 * 24 = 120`

Comment: Sorry guys. Much appreciate your help but I don't get it. We didn't loop through. All this function does is if number is equal to 0 then return 1. How num * factorialize(num - 1) gives us 5 * factorialize(5-1) = 5 * 4! = 5 * 24?

Comment: Did you try walking through the code with a debugger? That would have helped you understand what is going on. By the way, what happens if you pass this a negative number? Also, strongly recommend indenting your code properly to maintain your sanity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from your question

> Assume we have an integer 5 as an argument. Must be 5 * factorialize(5-1) = 5 * 4 = 20. How we getting to 120?

When you were starting with `5 * factorialize(5 - 1)`, you evaluated 5-1 to be 4 (correct), but then you dropped the call to factorialize that. That's how you were getting 20.

Let's take that `factorialize` function and step through it.

```
function factorialize(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return num * factorialize(num - 1);
}

factorialize(5)
```

Since 5 was passed into factorialize, the local variable `num` is not equal to 0. This function then returns `num * factorialize(num - 1)`. Since `num` is 5, we'll go ahead and start plugging in numbers.

```
= 5 * factorialize(5 - 1)
```

Now here, we're calling `factorialize` again, this time passing in 4 (5 - 1). This is still not equal to 0, so let's replace `factorialize(5 - 1)` with its return value (since `num` is 4 in this call to factorialize, we'll be returning `4 * factorialize(4 - 1)`

```
= 5 * (4 * factorialize(4 - 1))
```

As with before, we're now calling factorialize again, this time passing in 3.

```
= 5 * (4 * (3 * factorialize(3 - 1)))
```

And so on

```
= 5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * factorialize(2 - 1))))
```

And so forth

```
= 5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * factorialize(1 - 1)))))
```

Now `factorialize(0)` returns 1; the if-statement finally evaluates to true. This is the *base case*, a known answer that can be expressed without further using recursion. Substituting that, we get this:

```
= 5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * 1))))
```

This is mathematically equivalent to

```
= 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
```

Which equals

```
= 120
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. Thank you for the walk through and thank you for being nice. I don't understand people down voting for my curiosity, I'm trying to learn and really get the logic behind it. Thank you indeed.

Comment: You're welcome, @EdgarKiljak. Recursion is one of the harder concepts to understand in computer science, so sometimes, stepping through step-by-step really helps!

Comment: @torazaburo, I tackled this question with the following two assumptions: the asker did not write the original code, and this was a basic general recursion problem instead of a JavaScript-specific question. Besides, as I explained at the beginning of my answer, the actual logical fallacy was evaluating `factorialize(5-1)` as `4` instead of as `factorialize(4)`.

Comment: @torazaburo I'm a learner. Doing my first steps in coding. Going through Free Code Camp basic algorithms. I have only covered JavaScript's basics. Instead of helping and give me an advice your are being intolerant. I do respect you as a developer. You have also been a code newbie long time ago. Why you feel so annoyed? I'm working full time and studying for BSc Computing which is not a Software Engineering not even close. I'm super hungry for all this stuff. Doing as much coding as I can on my own. Every minute I have a free time. Your comments do not encourage me to progress at all. Sorry

Comment: @EdgarKiljak I'm not being intolerant. I was suggesting, perfectly calmly, that you learn and use basic tools which are at the heart of the JS programming process, while giving you the benefit of the doubt as to whether or not you already have and perhaps simply did not think to use them in this case. I'm not sure where you find evidence of me being "annoyed". Being a newbie is not a good excuse for not learning tools. Would being a newbie carpenter be a good excuse for not knowing what a hammer is?